which file ends up in the repository when I merge?
I'm teaching myself git and I was wondering: if I merge a branch with master and a commit in the branch is older than a commit in master that alters the same file, do I end up with the branch (older) version of the file or the master (newer) version of the file?
I don't have a specific scenario this applies to, I'm just thinking ahead and seeking clarification.

If you're unsure of what a Git merge does, the English definition of "merge" is a good starting point.

git merge takes into account the changes of the file and will attempt to take the changes from both. When it is incapable of doing so, then you have a merge conflict that requires you to manually solve the two conflicting changes. Yet, if both were changing the same file but in different regions of the file, then git will generally be able to merge both.
So git is not picking the file from the branch or from master, but instead git is creating a synthesis of the two versions of the file, which, if succeeds, then all good. If it fails, then you will need to solve the merge conflict.

thank you very much for the succinct answer.  i added it to my notes.  your response led me to avenues of research as to how to solve a merge conflict, which i am grateful for and am now learning about.

@AtreusArcheus happy to help.
